# Caching Twitter Results with Dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, twitter

I'm new to Ruby (and Rails) and was hoping you could help clear up some confusion I'm experiencing.

I'm trying to integrate the [Twitter gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) into my website in order to get a user's latest tweet, and grab the link to their profile picture. The gem works great up until (what I think is) the 100th API call in an hour, after which Twitter will cut you off.

From what I've gathered, I need to cache the result for ~1 minute using memcache. There was some great [pseudocode here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392486/simple-way-to-cache-twitter-gem-tweet-in-sinatra) but unfortunately, it was a bit over my head. I was hoping I could get some more specifics.

At the moment, I'm unsure where would I place that code? I want to display the twitter information in the application layout view, so would it go into a method in the application_helper.rb file?

My best attempt at figuring this out resulted in the following code, which throws a "Missing Helper File" error.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  require "memcache"

  def twitter
    cache = MemCache.new
    twitter = cache.get("twitter").first
    if twitter.nil?
      begin
        twitter = Twitter.user("TwitterName") 
        cache.set("twitter", twitter, :expires_in => 1.minute) if twitter
      rescue
        twitter = default
      end
    end
    return twitter
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First enable caching and memcache for your environment (e.g. config/environments/production.rb)

```
# Use a different cache store in production
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

Then in the view you want to show tweets do something like this

```
<% cache("tweets", :expires_in => 42.minutes) do  %>
 <% Twitter.user_timeline("User").each do %>
    .....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Sorry for the late response, my internet was down. Out of curiosity, are there any advantages to using memcache instead of dalli?

Comment: You mean the difference between the old memcache driver and dalli?

Comment: Yeah, I guess. Are they just different wrappers then?

Comment: dalli is new, the old driver is unmaintained.